# "Publish date" custom variable in Google Analytics, how to search between two dates?

Tags: google, google-analytics, wordpress

We have the two custom variables on our WordPress site:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'pubDate', 'June 6, 2014']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'author', 'Sam']);
```

The first variable is the date that the post was published.

How do we search for all posts between two dates using this value? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you cannot filter between dates like that. The filter reference is [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterOperators). There is one way however to do what you are trying to do. I'm afraid it will only work for the future though. You need to change your custom dimension ( or add a new one) and convert the date into an EPOCH timestamp. That is the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 in seconds, i.e. a number. When it is a number you can then filter in your query by converting your query dates into epoch stamps and then using the `ga:customVar1>=1457470303` filter syntax in your query.